# C#: How to get a value from a query string containing another url with multiple query params?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, url

When a url containing a query params that has a URL containing query params like this:
`https://example.com/login/login.ashx?redirect_url=https://example.com?test=11&test2=22&test3=33`

How can I then get `https://example.com?test=11&test2=22&test3=33`from that Url?

I've tried this with no luck

`redirectUrl = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.Url.Query)).Get("redirect_url");`.

This results in:
`https://example.com?test=11`
and I want `https://example.com?test=11&test2=22&test3=33`

Comment: `&test2=22&test3=33` belongs to the `login.ashx` URL, not the `redirect_url` value, because the `&` characters are not properly encoded to be part of the `redirect_url` value. The login URL was constructed incorrectly, so garbage in, garbage out. The only way to get what you want is to fix how the login URL is constructed in the first place.

Comment: So your question should show how you're constructing the login URL and ask what you're doing wrong there.

Comment: @madreflection You are totally right, and I feel stupid for not seeing this. The fix was this: ```$"{ResolveUrl("~/")}login/login.ashx?redirect_url={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)}"```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any url parameter that contains url string separators should be UrlEncode'd first.

So you need to System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(string value) your parameter url first.

```
var urlEncodedParameter = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode("https://example.com?test=11&test2=22&test3=33");
```

then create url

```
var url = $"https://example.com/login/login.ashx?redirect_url={urlEncodedParameter}";
```

Then redirect to that.
And you will not need to parse that parameter on the controller.
It will work on the endpoint with signature like this

```
public IActionResult Login(string redirect_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to get full url from browser:

```
string full_url = HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl().ToString();
```

Then you need to check that full url for existing "redirect_url" in it and if it exists you can use [Substring(int position)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-7.0) method. But before we need to know position of "redirect_url", so we can use [LastIndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=net-7.0) method:

```
if (full_url.Contains("redirect_url"))
{
    return full_url.Substring(full_url.LastIndexOf("redirect_url"));
}
```

If there is no "redirect_url" in your full_url we can simply return empty string like this:

```
return string.Empty;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).